# How to prove that $D_2$ conformally equivalent to $D_1$ simply connected is simply connected

Tags: complex-analysis

If we couldn't use the topological properties of simply connectedness and conformal maps, how can we prove the following:

> Let $D_1$ be a simply connected subset of $\Bbb C$, $D_2$ another subset of $\Bbb C$ such that there exists a conformal map $f:D_1\to D_2$. Then $D_2$ is simply connected.

I have an idea. We can consider $F_1$ the integral of $f$ in $D_1$ and $F_2$ the integral of $f$ in $D_2$. Then, by the uniqueness of the integrals, we know that there exists $c\in\Bbb C$ such that $F_2(z) = F_1(z) + c$ for all $z\in D_1\cap D_2$. We can define
\begin{equation*}
G(z) = \begin{cases}
F_1(z)+c & \quad \text{, if $z\in D_1$}\\
F_2(z) & \quad\text{, if $z\in D_2$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I should prove that $G(z) = 0$ for all $z$, knowing that $F_1(z) = 0$ for all $z$. Is it enough to see that $c = 0$ and we would have it? If so, how can we prove it?

Thanks in advance.

> We consider $f$ a conformal map if it is holomorphic, injective in $D_1$ and $f(D_1) = D_2$. And we say that $D$ is simply connected if all cycle $\Gamma\sim 0 \;mod\; D$.

> A result that I used in here was that if we consider $D$ a domain if $\Bbb C$, $D$ is simply connected iff for all $f$ holomorphic in $D$ and all cycle $\Gamma$ in $D$, $\int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz = 0$.

Comment: Each conformal map is a homeomorphism and the latter obviously preserve simple connectedness. But maybe you are using some goofy definition of simple connectedness (there is no shortage of these)....

Comment: I wrote the definition of simply connectedness (in complex terms) at the end of the post. Our proffesor wants an analytic proof (i.e. without using any topological properties such as homeomorphisms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof using the characterization

> A domain $D \subset \Bbb C$ is simply connected if and only if $\int_\Gamma f(z) \, dz = 0$ for all cycles $\Gamma$ in $D$ and for all functions $f$ which are holomorphic in $D$.

works as follows:

Assume that $D_1$ and $D_2$ are domains in $\Bbb C$ such that $D_1$ is simply connected, and there is a conformal map $\phi$ from $D_1$ onto $D_2$. Note that the inverse function $\phi^{-1}$ is a conformal mapping from $D_2$ onto $D_1$.

Now let $f$ be holomorphic in $D_2$ and $\Gamma$ be a cycle in $D_2$. Then $\gamma =  \phi^{-1} \circ \Gamma$ is a cycle in $D_1$, and
$$ \tag{*}
 \int_\Gamma f(w) \, dw = \int_\gamma f(\phi(z)) \phi'(z) \, dz = 0
$$
because $f(\phi(z)) \phi'(z)$ is holomorphic in $D_1$ and $D_1$ is assumed to be simply connected.

---

*Remark:* If you are not convinced about the identity $(*)$ then choose a parametrization $\gamma:[0, 1] \to D_1$ of $\gamma$ and note that both sides are equal to
$$
 \int_0^1 f(\phi(\gamma(t))) \phi'(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) \, dt \, .
$$

---

With respect to your approach: I don't think that will work. You have to start with a holomorphic function $f$ and a cycle $\Gamma$ in $D_2$, and then you cannot talk of the “integral of $f$ in $D_1$.” Also $ D_1\cap D_2$ may be empty.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! I appreciate how you made that remark too, and the comment of my remark. I don't take offense into some feedback, even more so considering my approach wasn't too well-written.