Where in the proof is necessary the "simply connected" hypothesis in Caratheodory's Theorem?
The below proposition is from David C. Ullrich's "Complex Made Simple" (pages 264-265)

Proposition 14.5. Suppose $D$ is a bounded simply connected
open set in the plane, and let $\phi: D \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be a
conformal equivalence.  (i) If $\zeta$ is a simple boundary point of
$D$ then there exists $L \in \partial \mathbb{D}$ such that
$\phi\left(z_n\right) \rightarrow L$ whenever $\left(z_n\right)$ is a
sequence in $D$ tending to $\zeta$. (In other words, $\phi$ can be
extended continuously to the set $D \cup\{\zeta\}$, and the extended
function satisfies $\sigma(\zeta) \in \partial \mathbb{D}$.)  (ii)
Suppose that $\zeta_1$ and $\zeta_2$ are two simple boundary points;
choose corresponding complex numbers $L_1$ and $L_2$ as in (i). If
$\zeta_1 \neq \zeta_2$ then $L_1 \neq L_2$.

Proof. First we note that if $\left(z_n\right)$ is any sequence in $D$ tending to a point of the boundary then $\left|\phi\left(z_n\right)\right| \rightarrow 1$ : If $r<1$ then $K=\phi^{-1}(\bar{D}(0, r))$ is a compact subset of $D$ and hence there exists $N$ such that $z_n \notin K$ for all $n>N$; thus $\left|\phi\left(z_n\right)\right|>r$ for every $n>N$.
Now we prove (i). Suppose that $\zeta$ is a simple boundary point of $D$ and that $\left(z_n\right)$ is a sequence of points of $D$ such that $z_n \rightarrow \zeta$. Now the compactness of the closed disk shows that there exists $L \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and a subsequence $\left(z_{n_j}\right)$ such that $\phi\left(z_{n_j}\right) \rightarrow L$ (hence $|L|=1$ by the comments in the previous paragraph). To show that $\phi\left(z_n\right) \rightarrow L$ we need only show that every other convergent subsequence of $\left(\phi\left(z_n\right)\right)$ also tends to $L$.
Suppose not: $\left(\phi\left(z_n\right)\right)$ has two subsequences tending to different limits. Adjusting the notation a bit we may assume that $\phi\left(z_{2 n}\right) \rightarrow L_1$ and $\phi\left(z_{2 n+1}\right) \rightarrow L_2$, where $L_j \in \partial \mathbb{D}$ and $L_1 \neq L_2$. Now, since $\zeta$ is a simple boundary point, there exists a continuous curve $\gamma:[0,1) \rightarrow D$ and a sequence $\left(t_n\right)$ in $[0,1)$ such that $t_n \leq t_{n+1}, t_n \rightarrow 1, \gamma\left(t_n\right)=z_n$, and $\lim _{t \rightarrow 1} \gamma(t)=\zeta$.
Now let $\Gamma=\phi \circ \gamma$. Then $\Gamma:[0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$, and an argument as above shows that $|\Gamma(t)| \rightarrow 1$ as $t \rightarrow 1$. But the curve $\Gamma$ does not actually tend to a. single point of $\partial \mathbb{D}$, since $\Gamma\left(t_{2 n}\right) \rightarrow L_1$ while $\Gamma\left(t_{2 n+1}\right) \rightarrow L_2$. Thus $\Gamma$ nust actually "cross" some sector $S$ infinitely many times as it tends to $\partial \mathbb{D}$. So, at least for large $n$, there exist nunbers $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $t_{2 n}<a_n<b_n<t_{2 n+1}, \Gamma\left(a_n\right)$ lies on one edge of $S$, $\Gamma\left(b_n\right)$ lies on the other edge of $S$, and $\Gamma\left(\left(a_n, b_n\right)\right)$ lies in the interior of $S$. Let $\Gamma_n=\left.\Gamma\right|_{\left[a_n, b_n\right]}$.
Let $f=\phi^{-1}$. Then $f \in H(\mathbb{D})$ and $f$ is bounded. We have $f(\Gamma(t)) \rightarrow \zeta$ as $t \rightarrow 1$, since $f(\Gamma(t))=\gamma(t)$; thus $f \circ \Gamma_n \rightarrow \zeta$ uniformly, and by some lemma we get that $f$ is constant. This is a contradiction, since $f$ is actually a bijection fom $\mathbb{D}$ onto $D$.

I don't understand where simply connected set hypothesis is used in the proof. Why we need to asume that? Thanks!

because otherwise there would be no conformal equivalence with the (simply connected) disc? (If that is not clear to you look, e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175306/how-to-prove-that-d-2-conformally-equivalent-to-d-1-simply-connected-is-simp )

@Thomas but if I say that there exists a conformal equivalence, is not sufficient?

You can drop "simply connected" but then instead of $\mathbb D$ you take a bounded domain whose boundary is a disjoint union of finitely many round circles. There is an generalization of the Riemann mapping theorem due to Koebe which provides you with $\phi$. Then Caratheodory's    theorem extends as well.

The existence of a conformal equivalence implies that $D$ is simply connected, so strictly speaking this proposition could be stated without that hypothesis, starting instead with the sentence

Let $D$ be a bounded open set in the plane and let $\phi : D \to \mathbb D$ be a conformal equivalence.

Whether one states it the way the author does, or instead in this more abbreviated manner, is a matter of style. The author's way has, perhaps, caused you some confusion. This more abbreviated statement might cause a different kind of confusion, say, to someone who was led to wonder what the proposition has to say about the annulus $D = \{z \in \mathbb C \mid 1/2 < |z| < 1\}$ (it says nothing, of course, because that $D$ is not simply connected and so no $\phi$ exists).

Oh. So the propositions works without that hypothesis, with tacit assumption that $D$ is simply connected (by the fact that $\phi$ is conformal equivalence)

It's not even a tacit assumption. It's just a consequence of the hypothesis of the existence of $\phi$.
